# Git is extremely slow on Windows

Tags: windows-10, performance, git

I'm not sure what have been changed, but my Git installation started to be extremely slow on an average-sized repository. Others use Git with the same repository on similar machines.

Various commands working with local files are slow, e.g. `status` & `commit`. `push` is fast.

Windows 10, Git 2.11.0 64 bit, high CPU consumption.

Typical problems and solutions already ruled out:

- Antivirus
- Network drive
- `core.fscache`

`time git status` (from `git-bash` aka MinGW):

```
real    0m29.017s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Tracing performance with `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=true git status` unfortunately has shown only a single atomic chunk:

```
performance: 32.583549907 s: git command: git status
```

Comment: I cannot speak to your issues in particular, but I recommend starting with `prune`.  It should lighten the load on other operations you attempt.  Good luck!

Comment: `git prune` && `git gc` (took really long) w/o any noticeable effect.

Comment: hmm, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/24045966/2317829 which may be related.  Also, it would be interesting to see some tracing output of the slow operations (e.g. `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=true git status`)

Comment: I've tried all of these. tracing status gave no insights (see updated post)

Comment: Is it still slow with less CPU consumption?

Comment: compile git (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git.git) on your own with Visual Studio (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/commit/056b41311688e9f433fe28e6b3aa6687fa36ca70) to get PDBs. Now open cmd.exe as admin and run this: **wpr.exe -start CPU -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighCPUUsage.etl**. now do your slow git actions. after you did this, go back to CMD and press a key to stop logging. Zip the large ETL + your own generated PDbs for git and share the zip (onedrive share link)

Comment: Unfortunately at some point git become fast again and support engineers are unable to tell me what has been changed in the repo.

Comment: I can no longer add an answer to this question, but I had the same issue, fixed it, and I want to document it for whoever lands on this page again. Simply upgrading to Git 2.15 from 2.14 (not even opening a new terminal) gave me a 3x `git status` speedup. I believe it's this: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/1344

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485059/git-bash-is-extremely-slow-in-windows-7-x64/24045966#24045966

Comment: @RaghuRanganathan first two options were enabled by default in my version of git, the third one won't work—I tried to run `git gc` manually several times with no visible improvements.

Comment: I had this problem because my home folder (containing the `.gitconfig`) was on a network share. I fixed it by installing MSYS, and then installing git into MSYS with `pacman -S git`. This works because MSYS has a separate home folder.

Comment: If there is someone still struggling with this and when its related with AD/VPN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65824270/10995369 thats the trick that worked for me

Answer (score 11):

If you scenario is like mine, and you don't have an AMD Graphics Driver, then try creating a `HOME` environment variable which points to your user profile directory (e.g. `C:\Users\UserName`), as is suggested further down in:

[Git Bash Mintty is extremely slow on Windows 10 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888024/git-bash-mintty-is-extremely-slow-on-windows-10-os/43762587#43762587)

One caveat... the explanation in that link says to make a new System Environment Variable.

I was able to fix my problem by making a new User Environment Variable, which seems preferable to having a system-wide environment variable pointing to your personal home directory.

The PowerShell way of doing it:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `powershell`→<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```powershell
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Environment\ -Name Home -Type String -Value $Env:UserProfile
```

Answer (score 6):

This Stack Overflow post worked for me: *[Git Bash (mintty) is extremely slow on Windows 10 OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888024/git-bash-mintty-is-extremely-slow-on-windows-10-os/43762587#43762587)*

Old question, I know, but I recently encountered the problem and found the answer - so thought I'd proliferate. Essentially, it was an issue with the AMD Radeon Graphics Driver slowing down mintty. Go to [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), and disable AMD Radeon Graphics in favor of Intel Integrated Graphics. I've tried to find out why, but no luck so far.

Comment: So did this solution work for you are not because you are writing an answer and if you have not confirmed the posted solution you write about, then it's not really an answer and therefore you should read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Comment: I had only intel graphic chipset on that machine, so it's like I already did that. Also from my understanding of how modern software utilizes hardware, the chances mintty utilize GPU somehow are pretty slim.

There might be a bug in a driver making CPU stuck, but it's also very improbable situation.

Ah, and I don't even use minGW console — I use standard windows cmd with executables added to the PATH.

Comment: Disabling your graphics driver!!!!???  Not a solution.